# Linux remap capslock to iso <>| key

Tags: linux, xmodmap, capslock

Heres my .Xmodmap:

```
remove Lock = Caps_Lock
keycode 66 = less greater less greater bar brokenbar bar brokenbar
```

The greater an less signs are working but the pipe still does not want to.
What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Try `keycode 66 = less greater bar brokenbar` and then press the AltGr key at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

How did you configure the
Shift_L,
ISO_Group_Shift, and
ISO_Level3_Shift
keys? Notice that not all layers might be available, setxkbmap is the 'stronger' guy through which layers need to be enabled in the first place. See
http://grahamwideman.wikispaces.com/linux+--+keyboard+configuration,+xkb
 or try        `setxkbmap lv && xmodmap neo_de.xmodmap && xset -r 51` with http://neo-layout.org/neo_de.xmodmap as a working example which has a lot of layers.